# postgres rule update field based on unique value from subquery

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm able to update a field based in a subquery when I substitute `id_sitio` with a real value:

```
update sitios
set grado = (
    select count(lin_sit.id_lineamiento) as total
    from lineamientos_sitios lin_sit inner join sitios sit on lin_sit.id_sitio=sit.id_sitio
    where sit.id_sitio=1418
)
where id_sitio=1418;
```

But not when I implement the rule.

```
CREATE or replace RULE actualizar_lineamientos_sitios_view AS ON UPDATE TO lineamientos_sitios_view DO INSTEAD (
UPDATE lineamientos_sitios SET id_lineamiento = new.id_lineamiento, id_sitio = new.id_sitio WHERE (lineamientos_sitios.id_lineamiento = old.id_lineamiento AND lineamientos_sitios.id_sitio = old.id_sitio);
update sitios  set grado = (select count(lin_sit.id_lineamiento) as total from lineamientos_sitios lin_sit inner join sitios sit on lin_sit.id_sitio=sit.id_sitio where sit.id_sitio=new.id_sitio) where id_sitio=new.id_sitio;
);
```

I believe that the first update is irrelevant as it works, I'm not sure how to reference the `id` from the record I want to upload.

Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL 9.1 or newer, consider using a `DO INSTEAD` view trigger, they're way easier to get right.

Comment: Thank you Craig!, i'll take a look as  soon as i can and i'll tell you

Answer (score 1):

Hi Craig (everybody else is welcome ;) )

Thank you very much. You put me on the clue, but having some troubles with the  delete rule. The first rule works fine,  so i can upload the field grado based in a subquery. But calcularGrado2_view rule not makes the work..

```
CREATE RULE calcularGrado_view AS ON INSERT TO lineamientos_sitios_view DO INSTEAD (

update sitios  set grado = (select count(lin_sit.id_lineamiento) as total from lineamientos_sitios lin_sit inner join sitios sit on lin_sit.id_sitio=sit.id_sitio where sit.id_sitio=new.id_sitio) where id_sitio=new.id_sitio;

);

CREATE RULE calcularGrado2_view AS ON DELETE TO lineamientos_sitios_view DO INSTEAD (

update sitios  set grado = (select count(lin_sit.id_lineamiento) as total from lineamientos_sitios lin_sit inner join sitios sit on lin_sit.id_sitio=sit.id_sitio where sit.id_sitio=old.id_sitio) where id_sitio=old.id_sitio;

);
```

DO you know what could be wrong with the rule?
Thank you!

Comment: Does anybody knowks how implement a view rule to update a integer field  based on a agreggate  sbuquery when DELETE?. The rule'd update the table instead the view (not possible to update a view directely on postgresql). Thank you.

Comment: Someone can offer me a solution, or just a clue to try out?. Thanks